# Insert a row when the value changes in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a For loop that loops through a column and detects whether a value has changed. If the value has changed then it inserts a row.

```
Sub InsertRow()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("q3:q10")
    If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If

Next cell 

End Sub
```

The way I'm trying to do it compares the cell with the previous sell and if the values are not equal it inserts a row.

The line

```
If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
```

works.

However, line

```
cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

causes the excel to crash.

An example of the column would be:

| Column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 6 |

And I'd like to insert a blank row where the numbers change.

Comment: If you're inserting/deleting, you want to go in reverse order, so you're not counting the added/removed line items. A `For` loop with `Step -1` will get you there.  "It's not possible to loop backwards using the for each loop syntax," should be the first big hit if you try to find a way to reverse your `for each`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on comment based on your code:

```
Sub InsertRow()
    'Dim cell As Range
    Dim iterator as Long

    'For Each cell In Range("q3:q10")
    For iterator = 10 to 3 Step -1
        'If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        If Cells(i,"Q").Value <> Cells(i-1,"Q").Value Then
            'cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(i).Insert 'Inserting at your current row pushes your current row down one
        End If
    'Next cell 
    Next iterator 'FIXED
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I kind of understand what you're saying. I tried the code you wrote, but the ``` Next i ``` returns the error "Compile error: Invalid Next control variable reference".

Comment: @mlombar9 Change `Next i` to just `Next`

Comment: @mlombar9 sorry about that, had spelled out `iterator` rather than just using `i` and that is the error.